# Django Vue.js Axios PUT Not allowed 405

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios

I am developing a small inventory management project. I am trying to update the stock amount when some kind of a product is being withdrawn. I am using Axios and .put() function, and when I send the request it says 405 not allowed. I can't seem to understand what the problem is. I am sending the product id to the backend and using it to identify the product which stock amount I want to upgrade. Hope you will be able to point my errors and teach me how to make it work.

Here is the Views from Django:

```js
class materialWithdraw(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [authentication.TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [permissions.BasePermission]

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = WithdrawFormSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            material_id = serializer.validated_data['id']
            quantity_to_withdraw = serializer.validated_data['quantity']
            withdrawn_material = Listing.objects.get(id=material_id)
            withdrawn_material.quantity = withdrawn_material.quantity - quantity_to_withdraw
            serializer.save(quantity=withdrawn_material.quantity)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is the urls.py:

```js
urlpatterns = [
    path('all-materials/', views.allMarketingMaterials.as_view()),
    path('all-medical-lines/', views.allMedicalLines.as_view()),
    path('gastroenterologia/', views.gastroenterologiaMaterials.as_view()),
    path('withdraw/', views.materialWithdraw.as_view()),
]
```

and this is my script from Vue.js:

```js
export default {
  name: "Gastroenterologia",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      gastroenterologiaMaterials: [],
      quantity: 0,
      id:'',
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document.title = "Gastroenterologia";
    this.getGastroenterologiaMaterials()
  },
  methods: {
    getGastroenterologiaMaterials() {
      axios
        .get('/api/v1/gastroenterologia/')
        .then(response => {
          this.gastroenterologiaMaterials = response.data
          console.log(this.gastroenterologiaMaterials)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    },
    chooseMaterial(index) {
      const materialName = document.querySelector('#material-name')
      const materialType = document.querySelector('#material-type')
      materialName.textContent = this.gastroenterologiaMaterials[index].title
      materialType.textContent = this.gastroenterologiaMaterials[index].type
      this.id = this.gastroenterologiaMaterials[index].id
    },

    materialWithdraw() {

      console.log(this.title)

      const data = {
        'quantity': this.quantity,
        'id': this.id,
      }

      axios
        .put('/api/v1/withdraw/', data)
        .then(response => {
          return response
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }


  },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. The problem was my Axios request as well as the View model. Here is the solution for those who experience the same kind of problem.

Here is my Views.py:

```js
class materialWithdraw(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [authentication.TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [permissions.BasePermission]

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        withdrawn_material = Listing.objects.get(id=pk)
        serializer = WithdrawFormSerializer(withdrawn_material, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            quantity_to_withdraw = serializer.validated_data['quantity']
            withdrawn_material.quantity = withdrawn_material.quantity - quantity_to_withdraw
            print('Success', quantity_to_withdraw, withdrawn_material.quantity)
            serializer.save(quantity=withdrawn_material.quantity)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and Axios:

```js
    materialWithdraw() {

      console.log(this.title)

      const data = {
        'quantity': this.quantity,
      }

      axios
        .put(`/api/v1/withdraw/${this.id}`, data)
        .then(response => {
          return response
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
```